# c++ using text files to make graphs

Tags: c++, graphics, file-io

So I want to use large text files with baby names, and the frequency of the name being used each year since 1880. I have a text file for each year with names and frequencies. I need to read in the text files and have the user input a name and a year that they want to see the frequency of (which is not the problem I have, I can do that). When the user inputs the name and year, though, I want to have a line graph show up that shows the frequency of the name as the y-axis and the years as the x-axis. I am using myro which allows the use of graphics and what not, but where should I start? I'm very lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When I was doing something similar (but in ASCII) to that before, I quickly realized there were two options:
A)The graph will not be well looking, and actually fit only SCREEN_WIDTH years, 
B)The graph will show only the most interesting years
C)The graph will not fit on one screen.
D)You will somehow sum up values not fitting to one screen.

Personally I choose option C), which can be solved as follows:
Each column is one year (or one year range). Set the row of that column, at the same height as the frequency value equal to "COLORED".

The number of rows has the same problem, as we can only fit SCREEN_HEIGHT elements there. As long however, as the shape of the line was shown, to me it was acceptable, so sacrifice of precision was worth it.